# jQuery: toggle('slow') animation from top down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I use jQuery's `toggle('slow')` animation to make a hidden div appear/disappear. It expands from the upper left to the bottom right.

How can I make it expand from the top towards the bottom, instead (no left-to-right growth)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [`.slideDown('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/). Note that this will only work for sliding down (to reveal) and sliding up (to hide). For anything more complex, you're looking for [`.animate(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [something from jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).

Comment: Thank you! For my dropdown menu, slideToggle and animate() DO NOT work as well as slideDown(). Your solution definitely eliminated some problems I was having with those functions, where when I moused over-off a sub-menu parent, the sub-menu would expand-contract in a very annoying way. Once I replaced slideToggle() with slideDown(), my dropdown menu worked perfectly.

Answer (score 28):

You could use `.slideToggle('slow')`.

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/stbV7/)***

Comment: @bevanb Have you checked the demo?

Comment: yes, it seems to work fine there. Note that it works the same as `.toggle('slow')`. Doesn't work in my app though; still working it out.

Comment: @bevanb It will expand from the top towards the bottom, not like `.toggle('slow')`, check the manual.

Comment: Works as described in the demo, but not in my application. Note that toggle(slow) goes top to bottom in the demo as well.

Comment: slideToggle does not work the same as slideDown. I had problems with slideToggle in my dropdown menu, where when I mouseover the child of the grandchild (the third-tier menu), there was an obnoxious jiggling because it "toggled" on/off/on/off. Once I replaced it with slideDown(), the problem instantly went away.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.animate` (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead. That way you can set the CSS properties before and after the expand and only alter the height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an  with onclick **$('#DIV-ID').toggle('slow'); return false;**

Just like this: `<a onclick="$('#DIV-ID').toggle('slow'); return false;">DROP DOWN</a>`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question do not fix the issue of OP; his problem is NOT to start the animation, his problem is that he got the wrong type of animation (kind of...).